# Python looping try/except not breaking out of function after success

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-requests

I'm having difficult understanding why my beneath while/try/except isn't breaking after a success.

```
def api(url, data, head):
  tries = 6
  for i in range(tries):
      try:
        req = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head, timeout=3)
        req.raise_for_status()
      except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
          if i < tries - 1: # i is zero indexed
              continue
          else:
              raise
      break
```

The api function is being called within another function:

```
a():
    api(url1, data1, head)
    api(url2, data2, head)
```

The loop works as intended and I receive a 200 status typically on the first POST call. Once succeeded, it doesn't exit the function and continue in function `a()` in which it was being called from.

I have also made use of a similar while/try/except function as shown beneath but I'm receiving the same issue.

```
def api(url, data, head):
  retries = 0
  success = False
  while not success and retries < 7:
    try:
      req = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head, timeout=3)
      req.raise_for_status()
      success = True
      break
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
      wait = retries * 15;
      logging.info(err)
      logging.info("Issue with the request, retrying")
      time.sleep(wait)
      retries += 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand I am not making correct use of the continue/break/raise clauses. I have tried looking into this but I'm getting nowhere.

Thanks.

-
I have included the entire script beneath for clarity sake and understanding.

```
import logging, re, time
import adal
import requests, json
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    head = OAuth()
    team = createBaseTeam(head)
    appendSharedChannels(head, team)

# def OAuth():

#   return head

# def createBaseTeam(head):

#   return team_id

def appendSharedChannels(head, team):
  time.sleep(30)
  # Create sahred channels
  incident_alert = ''''''
  reporting = ''''''
  updates = ''''''

  obj_incident_alert = json.loads(incident_alert)
  obj_reporting = json.loads(reporting)
  obj_updates = json.loads(updates)

  url = "sanitised"
  
  api(url, obj_incident_alert, head)
  api(url, obj_reporting, head)
  api(url, obj_updates, head)

# def appendSharedChannels(head, team, channel):
#   time.sleep(30)

def api(url, data, head):
  tries = 6
  for i in range(tries):
      try:
        res = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head, timeout=3)
        return res
      except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
          if i < tries - 1: # i is zero indexed
              continue
          else:
              raise
```

Comment: "I receive a 200 status typically on the first POST call. Once succeeded, it doesn't exit the function and continue in function a() in which it was being called from"  ...are you sure this is all true?  because code does not look obviously wrong to me

Comment: don't worry about my deleted answer, I didn't know about `raise_for_status()`

Comment: @JamesLin, your answer was perfectly fine

Comment: @Anentropic it doesn't. It attempts the same POST request using the same data and because of that, it returns a 400 status. The solution that James posted worked.

Comment: well, no completely, cos if the status is fine, `raise_for_status()` should just pass thru, I suggest you print out the status code to see, I suspect the `raise_for_status()` was raising exception and gets caught in your except block.

Comment: I see, so I'm guessing a return statement is required after the raise_for_status(), if no error presents itself, req will be returned.

Comment: I think the problem is not what you described in the question. `break` will exit the loop just fine. `return` is not what makes it work for the problem as described, I guess there is some interaction with the calling code not shown?  No doubt it makes sense to return the response though (and `req` is bad var name - it's a response not a request).  And I'll repeat my comment from the deleted answer that you probably shouldn't retry 4xx status, only 5xx.

Comment: Thanks @Anentropic, good point on the shoddy naming convention. In regard to not showing the entire code, what I've described is the meat of it. api() is being called once from another function. The issue is that the data being passed is the same whereas it should be different. data1 and data2 are two completely different JSON objects.

Comment: I come back to this "Once succeeded, it doesn't exit the function and continue in function a() in which it was being called from"  ... it sounds like that is not the case, and instead the problem is something around making the subsequent `api` call with wrong arg values?

Comment: @Anentropic I have updated the question with my solution to show how I'm calling api(). Some of the values are missing/sanitised for security reasoning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beneath solution works as expected

```
def api(url, data, head):
  tries = 6
  for i in range(tries):
      try:
        req = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head, timeout=3)
        return req
      except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
          if i < tries - 1: # i is zero indexed
              continue
          else:
              raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Your back-off strategy could be improved by utilising the retry mechanism available within the *requests* module.

You also need to think about what should happen if the number of retries are exhausted.

Maybe this will improve things:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import logging

RETRIES = 7


def api(url, data, head):
    last_err = None
    for r in range(RETRIES):
        try:
            requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head, timeout=3).raise_for_status()
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            last_err = err
            logging.info(err)
            logging.info("Issue with the request, retrying")
            time.sleep(r*15)
    else:
        raise last_err
```